# jquery - check/uncheck customized checkbox with hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input, hidden

I have this in **HTML**

```
<div class="my-checkbox">
    <label>I do agree</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="agreement" value="0">
</div>
```

and this in **jQuery**

```
$('.my-checkbox').on('click', function()
{
    if($(this).children('[type="hidden"]').val() == 0)
    {
        $(this).children('[type="hidden"]').val(1);
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).children('[type="hidden"]').val(0);
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

When I click `.my-checkbox`, it will change the value to `1` and add class `active` and when I click it again vice-versa. It works correctly but in mobile device when I click it it changes the value and set to `active` but when I click it again, it changes the value but the `active` class doesn't remove. How do I know that? just by double clicking and submit the form and the result was => you should agree with agreements.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please try 'change' instead of 'click'?'

Comment: the event I want is clicking on the div and changing the input value.

Comment: um, why are you not using a checkbox? You are litterally reinventing the checkbox.....

Comment: anyway it didn't work even after changing it to 'change'

Comment: I have my own style with div @epascarello

Comment: So you can not hide the checkbox and style the label?

Comment: yes that's right the second statement which is removing the active class doesn't work. I don't know it doesn't run or it runs but in view we can't see that. However when I click it, and click it again and submit the form it returns "you should agree with agreements" so it shows that the value will change but the active class doesn't change. I think I should trigger blur for it however it doesn't work either. but when I click on it second time and click on another element it changes the style. So how can I set it unfocused?

Answer (score 2):

Makes no sense to reinvent the checkbox when it is a is simple CSS to change the style to make it work the same way. No adding/removing classes. No JavaScript needed, just a simple CSS selector.

```css
#agree + label {
   color: red
}

#agree:checked + label {
   color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="my-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agreement" hidden>
    <label for="agree" >I do agree</label>
</div>
```

---

Now why does your code not work?

```
if($(this).children('[type="hidden"]').val() == 0)  <-- If zero
{
    $(this).children('[type="hidden"]').val(0);  <-- set zero
```

You are not toggling to 1. You have your logic reversed.

Comment: add a required attribute also and everything is perfect

Comment: No because I have been modifying the code that was a mistake between 0 and 1. I edited it. Because there must be a lot of modifying in my code so I can't do that. But I have found something, when I click on the checkbox i.e. div, click it again and click on another element like input it shows the changes. So I think if I set focus an element after setting it to active it will work. isn't it? Now how can I do that?